# How do I add objects to the Workshop?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I created a mod for Skyrim, but I don't know how to add it into the Workshop.
How would I go about adding it to the Workshop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Uploading to Steam Workshop is handled by the Creation Kit.](http://www.creationkit.com/Uploading_To_Steam_Workshop) Open the **File** menu and choose **Upload Plugin and Archive to Steam** to open the uploading interface.